# Custom loss function in NN

Tags: neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to build a simpleRNN network with custom loss function. I am predicting bmi based on 25 different features. My dataset is unbalanced and have outliers and want to predict better on the outliers. Rather it is more important to predict better on outliers.
For my custom loss function I have added condition that if the loss is greater than 2 units then I want to penalize those observations more.

```
import keras.backend as K

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = K.abs(y_pred - y_true)
    wt = loss * 5

    loss_mae = K.switch((loss > 2),wt,loss)
    
    return loss_mae

model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=64, input_shape=(25, 1), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(32, activation="linear")) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam')
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.summary()
model.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

sample predictions after running this code

```
preds=[[16.015867], [16.022823], [15.986835], [16.69895 ], [17.537468]]
actual=[[18.68], [24.35], [18.07], [15.2 ], [13.78]]
```

As you can see, the prediction for 2nd and 5th obs, is still way off. Am I doing anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is very wrong is that you should *never* have a dropout on the output neuron. Apart from this:

- activation function of hidden layers **should not** be linear (`model.add(Dense(32, activation="linear"))` should be `model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))`)
- A neural network should always be able to overfit to your training data, and this should be your debugging state before worrying about generalisation, consequently:

  - Do not use dropout (this only makes fitting harder, you can experiment with it once you are concerned about generalisation)
  - Your network is somewhat tiny,try making it much wider and see if your predictions improve
  - overall MAE is much worse behaved learning signal than MSE, which also automatically penalises outliers a lot, why not use it?
  - Consider normalising your data, neural networks work well with their default initisalisations if both inputs and targets are in somewhat bounded space, preferably in [-1, 1] or [0, 1] scale.

Comment: Thank you @lejlot for your inputs. I did realize my error on dropout after posting the question and fixed it. I had also used minmaxscalar to normalize. I incorporated all your suggestions but sadly there is no improvement. I added 6 more layers and used only mae. Anything more tips you have to improve this?

Comment: instead of adding layers I would suggest you making each much bigger. I am also quite confused why would you use RNN for this task, there is no time here, no varied length dimension, this looks like a task for a normal MLP.

Comment: Its my project requirement hence using RNN. Also do you think log transformation can help here? My data is skewed but i read on other sites/blogs that for NN normalized data is the preference.

Comment: requirement or not, starting with normal network will answer the question if the issue is with the model or data/code.